# Quantcast numbers vs. Google analytics numbers. Why the discrepancy?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, traffic

Quantcast claims that SO receives 1.8 mm unique visitors per month, and 17.2 pageviews per month: http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com

You can't see this part, but Google Analytics shows:

```
3,768,298 Absolute Unique Visitors
18,180,413 Pageviews
```

for the last month.

Pageviews seem to match up very closely.  Why would there be such a huge difference in unique visitor counts?

(It makes a big deal in the ranking scheme for Quantcast.)

Comment: Although you're referring to the traffic data of Stack Overflow, I don't think this constitutes as a meta question, as the question is really about discrepancies between GA and Quantcast. This might be better off on ServerFault.

Comment: or superuser....

Comment: I think it's meta enough to be here, since it is very site specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC Quantcast estimates the unique visitors from the users that are [carrying their cookie information.](http://www.quantcast.com/docs/display/info/Glossary)

> Uniques are a standard measure of audience size available from sophisticated analysis tools including Quantcast. Although many tools label them "visitors," uniques technically count the distinct cookies received from or sent to visitors.
>
> Quantcast is the only measurement service to provide audience data for both unique cookies counts and people. The Quantcast inference-based direct measurement model takes into account numerous factors including the frequency of visitation and the respective balance between work and home access to build a translation of cookies to people that is unique to each digital media property.
>
> The model was introduced in June 2008 and is detailed in our white paper, 'Cookie Corrected Audience Data' available to view or download here.

More info [here.](http://www.quantcast.com/docs/display/info/FAQ#FAQ-FAQ7)

> As a courtesy, Quantcast provides 'rough' audience estimates for non-Quantified digital media properties. These rough estimates are just that - far from perfect. We strongly recommend non-Quantified publishers refine the accuracy of our reporting on their audience activity by joining the Quantcast Publisher program at absolutely no cost.

Comment: I read the paragraphs you quoted but I don't get it. :\

Comment: It's something to do with their secret sauce. :)

Comment: Also, Quantcast is flagged as an "Advertising" tracker with Ghostery which a lot of SO overflow users would be running and thus would likely have the entire "Advertising" group blocked.